# Accessing DbContext from custom Class .Net Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to access my DbContext from one handler class which is instantiated in the configure method of `Startup.cs` class. How Can Instantiate my handler class in order to use the db context registered with the dependency injection container in `Startup.ConfigureServices` method.

This is my code:

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    var connection = @"Server=MyDb;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Persist Security Info=True; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    services.AddDbContext<iProfiler_ControlsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

    //.........
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //.............

    options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new MyTokenHandler(MY INSTANCE OF DBCONTEXT HERE));
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);

    //..............

}
```

Handler Class:

```
internal class MyTokenHandler : ISecurityTokenValidator
{
    private JwtSecurityTokenHandler _tokenHandler;
    private iProfiler_ControlsContext _context;

    public MyTokenHandler(iProfiler_ControlsContext context)
    {
        _tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        _context = context;
    }

  public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)
   {

    var principal = _tokenHandler.ValidateToken(securityToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);

    var tblVerificationPortalTimeStamps = _context.TblVerificationPortalTimeStamps.ToList();   

   //......         

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First update `ConfigureServices` to return a service provider from the service collection.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    var connection = @"Server=MyDb;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Persist Security Info=True; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    services.AddDbContext<iProfiler_ControlsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

    //.........

    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    return provider;
}
```

Next update `Configure` method to inject `IServiceProvider`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider provider) {
    //.............

    var dbContext = provider.GetService<iProfiler_ControlsContext>();
    options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new MyTokenHandler(dbContext));
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);

   //..............

}
```